# Combining Two Differently Formatted Spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I'm relatively new to excel and am having some issues comparing two sheets of data. We're looking at the benefits over the fiscal year by month. One spreadsheet has the project ID on the left, and the savings of the project per month horizontally. The other spreadsheet is set up vertically, with one row for each month the project saves the company money. The project ID's are also on the left. My question is: How would you recommend reformatting the second spreadsheet to combine all of the savings for each ID and somehow line them up under the appropriate monthly columns? I think once I have it in the correct format, I'll be able to compare the two fairly easily.

Thank you!

Comment: It might be useful to provide some screenshots, with dummy values

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet is to use a pivot table on the second sheet, where the months are listed vertically. You can use the pivot table to put the months in the Columns, the Project ID's in the Rows, and the sum of the 'saved money' column in the "Values" section of the pivot.

Once the data in the pivot closely matches the data in your first sheet you can use vlookup or whatever you wish to help combine the values.

There are other methods too, like using `=sumproduct()` or array formulas to bring values in from both sheets and combine them, but since you are new to excel those may be a bit overwhelming, where a pivot table and some careful copy and pasting, or vlookups are a bit more user friendly.